# How to trigger / bind custom events in Backbone.js views?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I have a Backbone View that uses [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to implement a slideshow.

iScroll publishes an `onScrollEnd` event, but I cannot seem to bind/subscribe to it inside the View:

```
App.Views.Scroller = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'onScrollEnd' : 'scrollEnd'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.scroller = new iScroll('content-scroller', {
            onScrollEnd: function() {  
                self.trigger('onScrollEnd');
            }
        });     
    },

    scrollEnd: function(e){
        // never called :(
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

Comment: I also tried extending the scroller object with Backbone.Events

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your onScrollEnd event is bound to the view's top element; scrollEnd will be called when the view's HTML element received an onScrollEnd event.

But you are triggering an onScrollend event on your View object, not the element.

So you probably want to say `$(self.el).trigger('onScrollEnd');` instead, or perhaps call the function directly: `self.scrollEnd()`.

Comment: I ended up just calling the function directly. Seems to defeat the point but it works :)

Comment: Or less verbose `self.$el.trigger('onScrollEnd');`.

Answer (score 25):

It might not be obvious, but `event` property in backbone.js views is used only for DOM events. Custom events should be bound as [James Brown mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379290/how-to-trigger-bind-custom-events-in-backbone-js-views/8630126#answer-8029660).

Comment: For me this answer was just as important as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You should call the function directly or in your init, add this:

```
self.bind('onScrollEnd', self.scrollEnd);
```