# Backbone.js: capture custom events on jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a Backbone view for a search form. The form includes several elements, including a slider implemented in [jSlider](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/). I want to capture all changes to the form, and update the results shown accordingly.

I can capture the click events fine, but I don't know how to capture the slide event on jSlider - I know [how to bind custom events in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379290/how-to-trigger-bind-custom-events-in-backbone-js-views), but jSlider [seems not to have a way to bind it directly](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/).

Here's my HTML:

```
   <form id="searchform">
   <input type="text" id="city" />
   <input type="text" id="type" />
   <input id="price-jslider" type="slider" name="price" value="1;500" />
   </form>
```

And here's my Backbone code:

```
var SearchFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#searchForm'),
    events: {
      "click input": "updateResults",
      // how to capture slide event on jslider?
    },
    updateResults: function(e) {
      // do stuff 
    }
   });
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to capture this sort of event?

Comment: Does onstatechange function(value) not suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't know how to bind it using `trigger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an `onstatechange` function when initializing the jQuery slider:

```
var SearchFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#searchForm'),
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("#price-jslider").slider({
            onstatechange: function( value ) {
                self.updateResults();
            }
        });
    },
    events: {
      "click input": "updateResults"
    },
    updateResults: function(e) {
      // do stuff 
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! I just had to call `this.render()` from inside the view's `initialize` function.

Comment: I would kick it up a notch and use the $el context and take advantage of the view (ie, $('#price-jslider',this.$el).slider();
I'd even take it further by doing including the onstatechange in the events itself (ie, events: {'click input, onstatechange #price-jslider': 'updateResults'}) since both events uses the same handler.

Answer (score 0):

from jslider page

onstatechange function(value)
 Function fires while slider change state.

callback function(value)
 Function fires on "mouseup" event.

when you instantiate jslider, you define those function in option

```
$(whatever).jslider({
       onstatechange : function(v) {
                 //set your input value to v
                 $('#searchForm').trigger('click')
     }
   })
```